# Azure Maps on Internet Explorer

Tags: azure-maps

I built an Azure Maps App. It works great on Chrome and Edge. It does not work on Internet Explorer. I've already spent a couple hours trying to figure out why. My research hasn't led me to any specific reason it wouldn't work on internet explorer. Anyone here aware of anything?

Comment: Have you debugged in Internet Explorer or is there any error information when loading the page? You can debug the script in the page.

Comment: No errors. It just doesn’t load the information. I pull the Interactive Map demo and even it won’t load correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the cache of the internet explorer?

Comment: I went through all the typical things. Reset all security setting, did the regsvr32 "iexplorere.dll" nothing. I was able to get IE to send me an error code finally: Unhandled exception at line 435, column 4724 in https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/js/atlas.min.js?api-version=1.0
0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Incorrect function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to security settings in IE. Try viewing your pages through a HTTP server. I would recommend using a simple server like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).